# Lucene RegexQuery doesn't seem to apply Regex?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, lucene

Code:

```
private static void AddTextToIndex(string filename, string pdfBody, IndexWriter writer)
    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.Add(new Field("fileName", filename.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        doc.Add(new Field("pdfBody", pdfBody.ToString(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        writer.AddDocument(doc);
    }

protected void txtBoxSearchPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//some code
    string searchQuery = txtBoxSearchString.Text;
    Term t = new Term("fileName",searchQuery+"/i"); 
    RegexQuery regQuer = new RegexQuery(t);

TopDocs resultDocs = indexSearch.Search(regQuer, indexReader.MaxDoc); 

            var hits = resultDocs.ScoreDocs;
            foreach (var hit in hits)
            {
                var documentFromSearcher = indexSearch.Doc(hit.Doc);
                string getResult = documentFromSearcher.Get("fileName");
                string formattedResult = getResult.Replace(" ", "%20");
                sb.AppendLine(@"<a href=https://de.com.edu/search/COM-Syllabi/" + formattedResult+ ">" + getResult+"</a>");
                sb.AppendLine("<br>");
            }
}
```

Basically all I'm trying to do is use Regex so that I can match things exactly but I want the search to be case insensitive. But adding the `/i` option doesn't actually make it a regular expression, all it seems to do is make the search term literally whatever was entered in the text box concatenated with the `/i`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case sensitivity depends mostly on the `Analyzer` you use.

A `RegexQuery` is a `MultiTermQuery` which means it will get rewritten to something similar to a `BooleanQuery` with a `SHOULD` occurence on all the terms that match the regex.

At search, the terms in your index will be enumerated and matched against your regex. The matching terms will be added as clauses to the `BooleanQuery`.

Your regex obviously does not get through the analyzer, so you have to adjust it manually to match your terms.

And, the regex syntax does not support many features... [See the docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html).

Actually, I simplified the explanation, what really happens is more complicated because many optimizations take place (all the terms are not enumerated, the regex is compiled to a finite state automaton, the querty does not necessarily get rewritten to a `BooleanQuery` etc). But what happens behind the scenes will have the same outcome as what I've explained here.

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what you mean by adjusting it manually. When the time to search comes I'm not searching with a parser that specifies an analyzer. I'm creating an index with the SingleCharTokenAnalyzer, however, when I add items to the index, my fields are set to "NOT_ANALYZED", doesn't that mean that if a field isn't analyzed that the properties of the analyzer aren't applied to what's indexed? EDIT: I added some more code to my question to help create more context.

Comment: Ouch! You're defeating the purpose of Lucene by not analyzing your PDF body... Supposing it contains more than a few words, this will get extremely slow once you have more documents. Lucene's strength comes from analyzing the text. You should reconsider your whole approach there.

Comment: The issue I was running into is that, most of the analyzers don't search both the file names and the pdf text's accurately enough. Because some file names might be BIOL-1322-001IN-JohnsonFA2104.pdf, the Standard, Keyword, and Simple Analyzers can't pick it up due to how the tokenization is. And that's fine, the SingleCharTokenAnalyzer works great for the file names but it picks up occurances of strings in a word. For example, if I search for "Orr", I get hits on words like "correct". I'm trying to blend both with regex.

Comment: Take a look at the `PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper` class, it lets you choose different analyzers for your fields. I don't know your needs, but you still should tokenize the text properly and work with that. You may also be interested in `WildcardQuery` although the end result will be the same as `RegexQuery`, except wildcards are simpler. And of course you can write your own analyzer to match your needs, which is pretty easy.

Comment: Not really. It depends on your needs. An analyzer is nothing more than  an object wrapping a tokenizer and a token filter chain. Finding the right combination of tokenizer and token filters is the real challenge here, and entirely depends on your needs. There's a lot of token filters in Lucene (that do things like stemming, stop word removal, ascii folding, lowercasing etc), and of course you can write your own too. Take a look at the source code. Also, remember the analyzer you use for searching must be compatible with the one you use for indexing (ie they produce matchable tokens).